# Why does building liblzma fail with "cannot find the library"?

Tags: mingw, libtool

I installed mingw from their website. 
I installed the developer package which comes with iconv and intl, msys and all the other stuff.

I run `./configure` and then `make install`. While linking, it prints:

```
 ../../src/liblzma/liblzma.la  -lintl
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/home/keith/staged/mingw32/lib/libiconv.
la' or unhandled argument `/home/keith/staged/mingw32/lib/libiconv.la'
make[2]: *** [xzdec.exe] Error 1
```

I have no clue who keith is or why it looks there for the library.. I tried settings CCFLAGS CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS to my include and library folder `/usr/local/lib`

No cigar.. any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with the MinGW `gettext` package. Keith Marshall, the "keith" in question, explains a bit about what's going on [in a bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2108/#b29e/52aa) on the MinGW SourceForge site.

A rather ugly workaround is to actually create a `/home/keith/staged/mingw32` folder, then add symlinks to the necessary folders in `/mingw`, i.e.:

```
mkdir -p /home/keith/staged/mingw32
cd $_
ln -s /mingw/bin bin
ln -s /mingw/lib lib
```

(Note that if `/mingw` doesn't exist in your filesystem, you can create it by adding this line to the bottom of `/etc/fstab`:

```
C:/MinGW                /mingw
```

assuming, of course, you have MingW installed in `C:\MinGW`. Close the terminal window and re-run `msys.bat` for the change to take effect.)

You'll then need to [download `libiconv.la`](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/mingw_how_to.html#libiconv) from a person who has conveniently prepared the file, and copy it to `/home/keith/staged/mingw32/lib/`.

It's a terrible hack, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2216/), there is something wrong with the latest gettext package (gettext-0.18.3.2).

I've tried the following 2 ways. It seems both working well.

- Remove bad files

  pushd /mingw/lib/ && rm libasprintf.la libgettextlib.la libgettextpo.la libgettextsrc.la  libintl.la && popd

  Or you can just rename them. In fact, you will see /home/keith/... in these *.la files if you open them with text editors.
- Use gettext-0.18.3.1 package

  Close MSYS and run the following command to use the older version: mingw-get upgrade "gettext=0.18.3.1-1*" , with PATH=C:\mingw\bin;%PATH%, of course.