# How can I install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?

Tags: cygwin, mingw, msys, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to build some open source library. I need a package management system to easily download the dependencies. At first I am using [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) and [MSYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#History). But the included packages are limited. Someone told me to use [Mingw-w64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64) and [MSYS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64#MSYS2).

I downloaded the `mingw-w64-install` from [here](http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php/download). When running, it reports the following error. How can I fix it?

[image]

And by the way, from the Mingw-w64 download page, I see a lot of download links. Even [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) is listed. How are Cygwin and Mingw-w64 related?

[image]

My current understanding is, in the time of MinGW and MSYS, MSYS is just a nice addon to MinGW, while in Mingw-w64 + MSYS2, MSYS2 is stand-alone and Mingw-w64 is just a set of libraries it can work with. Just like Cygwin can download many different packages.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MinGW-w64 installer you used sometimes has this issue. I myself am not sure about why this happens (I think it has something to do with Sourceforge URL redirection or whatever that the installer currently can't handle properly enough).

Anyways, if you're already planning on using MSYS2, there's no need for that installer.

1. Download MSYS2 from [this page](https://msys2.github.io/).
2. After the install completes, click on the `MSYS2 UCRT64` in the Start menu (or `C:\msys64\ucrt64.exe`).

   If done correctly, the terminal prompt will say `UCRT64` in magenta letters, not `MSYS`.
3. Update MSYS2 using `pacman -Syuu`. If it closes itself during the update, restart it and repeat the same command to finish the update.

   You should routinely update your installation.
4. Install the toolchain: (i.e. the compiler and some extra tools)

   ```
   pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain
   ```
5. Install any libraries/tools you may need. You can search the repositories by doing

   ```
   pacman -Ss name_of_something_i_want_to_install
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   pacman -Ss gsl
   ```

   and install using

   ```
   pacman -S package_name_of_something_i_want_to_install
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gsl
   ```

   and from then on the GSL library will be automatically found by your compiler!

   Make sure any compilers and libraries you install have this package prefix: `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-`. Only use unprefixed packages for misc command-line utilities (such as `grep`, `sed`, `make`, etc), unless you know what you're doing.
6. Verify that the compiler is working by doing

   ```
   gcc --version
   ```

If you want to use the toolchains (with installed libraries) outside of the MSYS2 environment, all you need to do is add `C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin` to your `PATH`.

MSYS2 provides [several compiler flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76552264/2752075), UCRT64 being one of them. It should be a reasonable default.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the canonical name of a package that `pacman` can recognize?

Comment: Will it work if you install both 32 and 64 bit toolchains simultaneously?

Comment: @Colonel yes, it will install the toolchains (and any 3rd party libraries you install) in separate directories (/mingw32 and /mingw64).

Comment: To use in MSYS2 shell I had to do: PATH=/mingw64/bin:$PATH

Comment: @Toby I agree they take "the Arch Way" in explaining things, i.e. read the Arch wiki on pacman and you'd know nearly the same. A beginner's setup might be useful, although it is now on SO which should turn up on Google quite quickly :). (read this as: keep upvoting this answer :P)

Comment: Reading the pacman documentation took me about half an hour to figure out how to actually install things instead of just listing them, LOL - Much more used to yum or apt-get!

Comment: @Toby you need to work on your reading skills: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Installing_specific_packages.

Comment: @rubenvb Ah that is indeed easier! I was looking at https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html

Comment: Using `pacman` to install `mingw-w64` is a great advice. I faced the same issue while trying to install mingw-w64 behing a proxy. Installing MSYS2 first, setting environment variables for the proxy like http://superuser.com/questions/713582/mingw-installer-not-working-with-proxy  and following your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks so much for this post - this should seriously replace the [windows compilation guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide#Windows). Is there anything you can add to this about cross compiling? When using MSYS2 and following the guide, there are issues with using the --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32-. Perhaps this is unnecessary with how MSYS2 installs the gcc and instead relies on the order of environment variables specified in PATH?

Comment: In case you need cmake, you have to install `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` and *NOT* `cmake`. Normal cmake will lack generators for minGW.

Comment: Regarding step 5. (Open a MinGW-w64 shell): When the tools are installed using the Chocolatey packet manager the shell must be opened manually from the directory `C:\tools\msys64`

Comment: Beware that this instruction is not enough to get `std::thread` and `std::mutex` working in MinGW. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63582175/why-doesnt-my-compiler-recognize-include-thread-c) for more info.

Comment: Is it okay if I install mingW-w64 **SEPARATELY** using mingw-w64 install file, and then install MSYS2 through its x86_64 installer?

Comment: @Valsak yes, that's possible (the MSYS2 MinGW-w64 x86_64 GCC is a native compiler toolchain like any other). Just don't install the separate MinGW-w64 install inside the MSYS2 tree ir you'll mess up MSYS2's file tracking. By installing a separate toolchain, you can more easily stick to a specific GCC version, but you lose the convenience of having everyting updating as a whole.

Answer (score 61):

MSYS has not been updated a long time. MSYS2 is more active, and you can download it from [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/). It has both the `mingw` and `cygwin fork` package.

To install the MinGW-w64 toolchain ([reference](http://msys2.github.io/#main_content)):

1. Open the MSYS2 shell from the start menu
2. Run `pacman -Sy pacman` to update the package database
3. Reopen the shell, and run `pacman -Syu` to update the package database and core system packages
4. Reopen the shell, and run `pacman -Su` to update the rest
5. Install the compiler:

   - For a 32-bit target, run `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain`
   - For a 64-bit target, run `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`
6. Select which package to install; the default is all
7. You may also need `make`. Run `pacman -S make`

Comment: how do i install specific MinGW-w64 version like `x86_64-6.2.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1`?

Comment: Does that mean the mingw installer as described [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) is not necessary anymore? and I should just install msys2?

Comment: Link `Reference` is broken

Comment: any ideas on why msys2 shell would close itself after a second?

Comment: In case you need cmake, you have to install `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` and *NOT* `cmake`. Normal cmake will lack generators for minGW.

Comment: Important note -- when using the pacman upgrade commands, it may show a message telling you to force close the window -- it's important to actually obey the message

Answer (score 5):

You can now also get the stand-alone personal build of MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ which doesn't require any installation; just extract and its ready to use. This allow having multiple toolchains on the same system (e.g., one for Windows 32-bit and another for Windows 64-bit).

Comment: MSYS2 also supports multiple toolchains per installation (and multiple installations). Winlibs is indeed easy to use, but lacks a package manager (i.e. no prebuilt libraries) and a linux-like environment (can't build stuff using Autotools).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for your insights. I'm actually working on a package manager for winlibs, and I'm making it cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way, as far as I know, is to use [Chocolatey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet#Chocolatey) to install MinGW:

```
choco install mingw
```

Then check with the command `whereis gcc`. It is going to be installed in *C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin*.

one more thing, to get make working, just copie (or rename if you wish)
with copy mingw32-make.exe make.exe in *C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin*.

Comment: Re *"to be installed in C:\ProgramData"*: Doesn't that depend on the Windows version and the configuration of Windows?

Comment: `mingw32-make` and `make` are different things, and pretending one is the other won't do any good.

Comment: Does this install `pacman` (the package manager)? One of the main selling points of MSYS2 is its numerous packages...

Comment: `mingw32-make` is a version of `make` that has been ported to `Windows` with `MinGW`. It works in a similar way to make, but with some differences in syntax and behavior due to `Windows` difference.